How to arrange contents of multiple cells in google sheet into a cell



Column A
Column B




2
4


1
9



If I had a google sheets doc that looked something like this, how do I put them all into 1 line like "2 4 1 9".
I am new to google sheets and I know barely anything about it and would just like a method to do this if possible.

You just need TEXTJOIN(). Try-
=TEXTJOIN(" ",1,A1:B2)


